# IMPORTXML is not working properly

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function, importxml

In my [Google Spreadsheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AtjX3Ttg50IydHJzR1FMSkJyY0U1bHBSeWtrMDRSZ1E) I tried to pull out the data from booking.com. I retrieved Hotel name in column but does not work with every column. I referenced the formula correctly but it automatically changed to:

```
=CONTINUE(E1, 2, 1)
```

The cell highlighted red is where the problem lies.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the calls are going into multiple cells. Try wrapping each `importXML` function inside `noexpand()`.